# Numpy: can I do tensor Hadamard multiplication without einsum?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a rank four tensor A (say indices (a, b, i, j)) and a rank two tensor B (say indices (i, j)) and I want to compute a kind of Hadamard multiplication of them.

That is, if we call the product C, I want `C[a,b,i,j]  == A[a,b,i,j] * B[i,j]`. There is a fairly straightforward way to do this with `einsum` but I'm told there is a significant performance hit to using `einsum` as compared to methods like `tensordot`, but I couldn't find a good way to avoid it from the docs.

It's possible that I missed it; I'm new to tensors and not an expert on numpy.

Answer (score 4):

```
C = A * B
```

Following the [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), NumPy will line up the shapes of `A` and `B` starting from the last axes:

```
A: (a, b, i, j)
B:       (i, j)
```

and multiply corresponding elements of `A` and `B` together to create `C`:

```
   A[a, b, i, j]
*  B[      i, j]
== C[a, b, i, j]
```

Comment: Wait really? I thought the shapes had to match exactly for this to work? And what if I want to use other indices to multiply on?

Comment: @RichardRast: [Yeah really.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) The shapes don't have to exactly match if they can be broadcast against each other. As for other indices, it depends what you mean, but you can probably get it to work by broadcasting.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into broadcasting. I'm on a phone right now but if the answer works when I get home, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @Poik: "you have to have the broadcasted dimensions be different sizes from the others" - what? No you don't.

Comment: @Poik: Nope, it'll be the last two. Which axes get broadcast against which others never depends on how long the axes are.

Comment: Looks like I would want to use swapaxes, then this, then swapaxes again if I want to use different axes - - e.g. `C[a,i,j,b] == A[a,i,j,b] * B[i,j]`. Would that be the right way to approach it, or is there a builtin for this?

Comment: @RichardRast There is a builtin. `A*B[None, :, :, None]`. Equivalently `A*B[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]`

Comment: @RichardRast: For that, you could do `C = A * B[..., np.newaxis]`.

Comment: That's some interesting indexing. I'm having an associativity failure; is that indexing into B forcing into a rank 4 tensor, then multiplying?

Comment: It's adding a length one dimension at the beginning and the end, and length one dimensions are considered fair game to be broadcast into. Just adding the newaxis at the end, like he suggests is a simpler and equivalent way to do it. `np.newaxis` is just an alias for `None` behind the scenes, and is used to indicate there wasn't a dimension/axis here before, but we want it here.

Comment: Specifically, ["When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when 1. they are equal, or 2. one of them is 1"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules).

Comment: @Poik: Length 1 axes get special treatment when determining compatibility, but not in a way that affects the choice of which axis they get broadcast against. The choice of which axes get broadcast against which others never depends on axis length; if the axes are incompatible, the broadcasting will simply fail rather than trying a different axis matchup.

Comment: Yeah, That's why I deleted my comments above. I've already acknowledged that. You should really include details about your answer in the answer though (and probably remove the sentence that can be interpreted as condescending about it being straightforward). Would you like me to add to it?

Comment: @Poik: Answer expanded.

Comment: I like it. The newaxis thing would be nice too for others who stumble upon this, but they can read the comments and broadcasting link. Thank you.